# Fedora: How to reduce the permission requirements for mounting/writing on SATA HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, fedora, sata

I am using Fedora, Plasma spin. I have a couple of HDDs connected via SATA. Unlike Ubuntu and its kin, mounting the drives requires a password by default, and they are mounted as read-only. How can I disable these extra security measures? I'd even type the password every time I mounted them if I were at least able to write to them. I remember a need to do something with /etc/fstab, but I'd like this to extend to all and any drives I boot with if possible.

Comment: Editing the `fstab` (or using any tool that does the same like Gnome Disks) is indeed the way to automatically mount additional partitions.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have confirmed that now, but I still have no idea how to get write permissions.

Comment: First things first, if it's a NTFS formatted partition on a dual-boot with Windows you need to disable Fast Startup (in Windows), a must when dual-booting. Other simply add to the fstab with the correct authentication.

Comment: @ChanganAuto it is an NTFS file system with Windows 8.1 on dual boot. How do you mean “correct authentication”? Is that only if it’s not an NTFS etc?

Comment: @ChanganAuto fast startup was already turned off.

Comment: Yes, user authentication may be needed if the partition has a different owner than the current user requesting access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144964/discussion-between-thelabcat-and-changanauto).

Answer (score 0):

The read-only part turned out to be because of left over fast boot data from Windows, and clearing this by turning off fast boot (or in my case booting and shutting down a different Windows install with fast boot already turned off) fixed that problem.

As for authenticating to mount the drives, I created a directory in /mnt and added an entry to /etc/fstab to mount the drives there every boot. Look up "how to auto-mount hard disks in Linux with /etc/fstab" for more info.